# Animating SVG polygons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I wrote a code to drawing polygons:

```
  var svg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
  svg.setAttribute('width', '100%');
  svg.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
  document.querySelector('#bg').appendChild(svg);

for(var x = 0; x < polygons.length; x++){
  var polygon = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'polygon');
  polygon.setAttribute('points', polygons[0 + x]);
  polygon.setAttribute('fill', polygons[0 + x][1]);
  svg.appendChild(polygon);
}
```

My full code with polygon points:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WrqrbB

I would like to animate this polygons similar to this animation:
http://codepen.io/zessx/pen/ZGBMXZ

How to animate my polygons?

Answer (score 1):

You can

- call an animation function to manipulate your coordinate values as desired,
- convert them to a string, e.g. using `.join()`,
- send the resulting string back to the polygon as its `points` attribute value, redrawing the shape (as you were already doing when you initially created your shapes), and
- have the animation function, when it is finished, call itself again at a reasonable built-in time-delay using `requestAnimationFrame`.

The following snippet gives a basic idea of what can be done.

*(Note that I've redefined the array `polygons` in my example so that it is different from what you had, but that was done for the sake of simplicity in this example.)*

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var polygons = [], numSteps = 100, stepNum = 0;
var coords = [
  [40, 20, 80, 20, 80, 60, 40, 60],
  [140, 20, 180, 20, 160, 50]
];

for (var x = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {  
  polygons[x] = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'polygon');
  polygons[x].setAttribute('points', coords[x].join());
  svg.appendChild(polygons[x]);
}

function anim() {
  for (var x = 0; x < coords.length; x++) {
    coords[x] = coords[x].map(function(coord) {
      return coord + 4 * (Math.random() - 0.5);
    });
    polygons[x].setAttribute('points', coords[x].join());
    stepNum += 1;
  }
  if (stepNum < numSteps) requestAnimationFrame(anim);
}

anim();
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

**UPDATE** The above snippet shows generally how to animate a polygon. In your case, however, there is a further issue. On your codepen demo, it is clear that you have hard-coded the point coordinates for each polygon separately. Thus, if you want to move one point, you're going to have to update coordinates in at least 2 if not more places, for every polygon that touches that point.

A better approach would be to create a separate array of all points and then define each polygon with respect to that array. (This is similar to how things are sometimes done in 3D graphics, e.g. WebGL.) The following code snippet demonstrates this approach.

```js
var svg = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0];
var polyElems = [], numSteps = 100, stepNum = 0;
var pts = [[120,20], [160,20], [200,20], [240,20], [100,50], [140,50], [180,50], [220,50], [260,50], [120,80], [160,80], [200,80], [240,80]];
var polyPts = [[0,1,5], [1,2,6], [2,3,7], [0,4,5], [1,5,6], [2,6,7], [3,7,8], [4,5,9], [5,6,10], [6,7,11], [7,8,12], [5,9,10], [6,10,11], [7,11,12]];

for (var x = 0; x < polyPts.length; x++) {
  polyElems[x] = document.createElementNS(svg.namespaceURI, 'polygon');
  polyElems[x].setAttribute('fill', '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16));
    // random hex color routine from http://www.paulirish.com/2009/random-hex-color-code-snippets/
  drawPolygon(x);
}

function anim() {
  pts = pts.map(function(pt) {
    return pt.map(function(coord) {
      return coord + 3 * (Math.random() - 0.5); // move each point
    });
  });
  for (var x = 0; x < polyPts.length; x++) {drawPolygon(x);}
  stepNum += 1;
  if (stepNum < numSteps) requestAnimationFrame(anim); // redo anim'n until all anim'n steps done
}

anim(); // start the animation

function drawPolygon(x) {
  var ptNums = polyPts[x];
  var currCoords = [pts[ptNums[0]], pts[ptNums[1]], pts[ptNums[2]]].join();
    // creates a string of coordinates; note that [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]].join() yields "1,2,3,4,5,6"
  polyElems[x].setAttribute('points', currCoords);
  svg.appendChild(polyElems[x]);
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

Comment: I tried animate my points but i don;t know how to declare my points: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPNgzv can you help me ?

Comment: I wonder if the key thing is for you to realize which points are duplicated. In any case, change the following: `var pts = [[1365.6,93.9],[1304.1,-8.7],[1926.8,-4.7],[1570.1,237.9],[1824.2,158.8],[1491.3,299.6],[1926.8,267.9]];` `var polyPts = [[0,1,2],[3,2,0],[3,2,4],[3,0,5],[2,4,6]];` And change the html to `<svg width="300" height="100" viewBox="1000 -100 1200 400"></svg>` altho you'll have to change this to add more shapes. I think it might be hard for you to do this all manually. Can you create your points and shapes programmatically, e.g. randomly? That's a whole different problem tho'.

Comment: I would like to animate this image: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adgLdK Do you have any idea how to animate this easily ?

Comment: Animate? Yes. Easily? Well...You are going to have to do the same thing that I did in my most recent comment to you, above. i.e. You are going to have to go through your polygon points, remove all duplications, put all those unique points in the `pts` array, go back through your polygons, figure out which points in the `pts` array are required by each polygon, and put those point reference numbers in the `polyPts` array. Then you can just use the routine I showed in my answer. That may be a fair bit of work, but it's the only way I can think of, starting from the polygons you currently have.

Comment: Ohh I don't know how to make :(( Can you animate 3-4 polygons in my example please ? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/adgLdK